# python interval

Tags: python, intervals

i've dev code for wifi scanning in python, now i trying to modify my code so it will scan wifi at specific interval, how this can be done

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally have two solutions:

- schedule to run the python script which refreshes WIFI info at various interval, using crontab or similar external device.
- keep the [python] program running and use [**threading.timer**](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects) to schedule calls to the WIFI checking routine at desired intervals.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it all within a long-running Python process (as opposed to a more normal cron-run script), the [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html?highlight=sched#module-sched) module in the Python standard library is probably the best way to schedule periodically repeated execution of a function or other callable (key trick: to schedule periodically, have each execution schedule the next one at appropriate delay -- the very classic, language-independent pattern to turn one-off scheduling into periodic repeats).

Comment: Them batteries again ;-)  When in doubt, check the std lib! Not that I have much use for scheduled events, but it's good to know it's there.  Actually, I may use more, now, for eg. for unit tests of asynch processes.  Thks!